# Installed a gem but it doesn't show up in the list of installed gems and doesn't run

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm

I'm trying to install `genghisapp` so I can have a UI for MongoDB. Anyone know what might be going on? I actually had `genghisapp` up and running earlier today but I downloaded and installed some system updates (ElementaryOS Freya), new video card driver, installed some game libraries, and then it stopped working.

```
➜  hpp-old git:(filestore) ✗ sudo gem install genghisapp
Fetching: genghisapp-2.3.11.gem (100%)
Successfully installed genghisapp-2.3.11
1 gem installed

//genghisapp isn't listed?

➜  hpp-old git:(filestore) ✗ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (4.2.3)
actionpack (4.2.3)
actionview (4.2.3)
activejob (4.2.3)
activemodel (4.2.3)
activerecord (4.2.3)
activesupport (4.2.3)
arel (6.0.3)
builder (3.2.2)
bundler (1.10.6)
bundler-unload (1.0.2)
erubis (2.7.0)
executable-hooks (1.3.2)
gem-wrappers (1.2.7)
globalid (0.3.6)
i18n (0.7.0)
json (1.8.3)
loofah (2.0.3, 2.0.2)
mail (2.6.3)
mime-types (2.6.1)
mini_portile (0.6.2)
minitest (5.8.0, 5.4.3)
nokogiri (1.6.6.2)
power_assert (0.2.4, 0.2.2)
rack (1.6.4)
rack-test (0.6.3)
rails (4.2.3)
rails-deprecated_sanitizer (1.0.3)
rails-dom-testing (1.0.7, 1.0.6)
rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.2)
railties (4.2.3)
rubygems-bundler (1.4.4)
rvm (1.11.3.9)
sprockets (3.3.1, 3.3.0)
sprockets-rails (2.3.2)
test-unit (3.1.3, 3.0.8)
thor (0.19.1)
thread_safe (0.3.5)
tzinfo (1.2.2)

// can't run genghisapp

➜  hpp-old git:(filestore) ✗ genghisapp
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs': Could not find genghisapp (>= 0) amongst [actionmailer-4.2.3, actionpack-4.2.3, actionview-4.2.3, activejob-4.2.3, activemodel-4.2.3, activerecord-4.2.3, activesupport-4.2.3, arel-6.0.3, builder-3.2.2, bundler-1.10.6, bundler-unload-1.0.2, erubis-2.7.0, executable-hooks-1.3.2, gem-wrappers-1.2.7, globalid-0.3.6, i18n-0.7.0, json-1.8.3, loofah-2.0.3, loofah-2.0.2, mail-2.6.3, mime-types-2.6.1, mini_portile-0.6.2, minitest-5.8.0, minitest-5.4.3, nokogiri-1.6.6.2, power_assert-0.2.4, power_assert-0.2.2, rack-1.6.4, rack-test-0.6.3, rails-4.2.3, rails-deprecated_sanitizer-1.0.3, rails-dom-testing-1.0.7, rails-dom-testing-1.0.6, rails-html-sanitizer-1.0.2, railties-4.2.3, rubygems-bundler-1.4.4, rvm-1.11.3.9, sprockets-3.3.1, sprockets-3.3.0, sprockets-rails-2.3.2, test-unit-3.1.3, test-unit-3.0.8, thor-0.19.1, thread_safe-0.3.5, tzinfo-1.2.2] (Gem::LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:256:in `to_spec'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:1231:in `gem'
    from /usr/local/bin/genghisapp:22:in `<main>'
```

**EDIT**

After doing some digging it seems that *part* of my problem was I installed as `sudo`. So...

`sudo uninstall genghisapp`

`gem install genghisapp` - this time without using sudo

And now `genghisapp` appears... BUT

```
➜  hpp-old git:(filestore) ✗ gem list                     

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (4.2.3)
actionpack (4.2.3)
actionview (4.2.3)
activejob (4.2.3)
activemodel (4.2.3)
activerecord (4.2.3)
activesupport (4.2.3)
arel (6.0.3)
backports (3.6.6)
bson (1.9.2)
builder (3.2.2)
bundler (1.10.6)
bundler-unload (1.0.2)
erubis (2.7.0)
executable-hooks (1.3.2)
gem-wrappers (1.2.7)
genghisapp (2.3.11)
globalid (0.3.6)
i18n (0.7.0)
json (1.8.3)
loofah (2.0.3, 2.0.2)
mail (2.6.3)
mime-types (2.6.1)
mini_portile (0.6.2)
minitest (5.8.0, 5.4.3)
mongo (1.9.2)
multi_json (1.11.2)
mustache (0.99.8)
nokogiri (1.6.6.2)
power_assert (0.2.4, 0.2.2)
rack (1.6.4)
rack-protection (1.5.3)
rack-test (0.6.3)
rails (4.2.3)
rails-deprecated_sanitizer (1.0.3)
rails-dom-testing (1.0.7, 1.0.6)
rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.2)
railties (4.2.3)
rubygems-bundler (1.4.4)
rvm (1.11.3.9)
sinatra (1.4.6)
sinatra-contrib (1.4.6)
sinatra-mustache (0.3.2)
sprockets (3.3.1, 3.3.0)
sprockets-rails (2.3.2)
test-unit (3.1.3, 3.0.8)
thor (0.19.1)
thread_safe (0.3.5)
tilt (2.0.0)
tzinfo (1.2.2)
vegas (0.1.11)
```

When I try to run it...

```
➜  hpp-old git:(filestore) ✗ genghisapp
zsh: command not found: genghisapp
```

Comment: Did you add the same gem as `gem genghisapp` in your Gemfile?

Comment: Where do I find my Gemfile? I'm not running Rails or anything. I'm simply following the instructions here, which just tell me to do `gem install genghisapp` - http://genghisapp.com/

Comment: Check this git issue. https://github.com/bobthecow/genghis/issues/168 This might help.

Comment: whew, ok, that was it. After doing some research on what `$PATH` does I managed to get it installed and running by editing `/.zshrc` with `export PATH="/home/myUserName/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"`

Comment: Glad to hear that you cracked it...